# Reading a word list into an array

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a simple hangman game, I have a small list of words in a .txt file separated by new lines. I put the word list into the assets folder. How can I find the path to the word list so I can use:

```
string[] wordlist = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("pathToFile");
```

Or is there another solution of converting the word list into a string array?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html. Like the answer I have little to no exp with Unity, found this link with a search engine, as you should be doing before asking

Comment: Please consider researching your question, before posting. Questions that show no research effort may receive down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Streamreader to load in the text in unity or set it as a text asset and parse it directly. This forum post should help give you an idea of what to do:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/read-from-textasset-line-by-line.327422/

Comment: This actually worked better for me cause the unity compiles my text file. This way I can access it even if it's encrypted.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included at least a summary of the method(s) suggested in the linked thread, so a user doesn't need to read through all the back-and-forth discussion at the link to follow it, and so that the answer is robust even if the linked thread is deleted or changes address. It would also be good to clarify that the thread recommends *not* using a StreamReader, but instead using Unity's [TextAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html) functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I have little experience with Unity, but it appears as though you can use `Application.dataPath` to obtain the correct path.

[Here it is at the API.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)